# HIVE or PIG as alternative for NETEZZA

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, netezza, bigdata

At my organization we are trying to use HIVE Or PIG as alternative

Primary goal :  reduce process time
NETEZZA process time : 90 min
looking to end process : within 30 min

How does process works:
Process is about to maintain incremental history.There are two tables history_table and new_table.History table maintains total history and new
_table has updated records.So every day updated records are added to history table.Process has very complex stored procedures (Joins/deletion/insert/update)
same process is being applied on multiple tables.Every history table has almost billions of records.

Doubts I have :

- Does HIVE/PIG perform better than NETEZZA ?
- Is UDF in hive a good alternative for Stored Procedure as I want to create generic process for multiple tables (where I can pass table name as argument) ?
- Which performs better HIVE or PIG for really complex joins with multiple condition, generating create statement dynamically and exception handling?

Comment: An UDF is *not* as stored procedure; it's a function.

Comment: Neither Hive or Pig are good at joins. Even simple ones.

Comment: There's an interesting reference from King Games: http://fr.slideshare.net/huguk/king-hug-uk >> they migrated their ETL **from** Hive to an analytic DB (currently Exasol) because it **just did not work**.

Comment: As far as "generating create statement dynamically and exception handling", I don't think Pig or Hive have very good support for either of those. As for UDF, Pig also has UDFs. Do they perform better? Really depends how hard you try to optimize the workload.

Comment: How much data are you trying to process? How many machines do you have?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Can you elaborate on why neither Pig nor Hive are good at joins? To me it looks like King's data size is not big enough to really warrant a Hadoop cluster...

Comment: Without some indication as to *why* your current process is taking 90 minutes there is really no way to even start on an answer.  For example, is it MPP disk or cpu bound, or is it host bound?  Is the Stored procedure trying to do row-by-row processing on Netezza, which is geared toward set-based prcoessing?  Or is the SP a good fit for Netezza, but happens to be saturating your current appliance?

Comment: @ScottMcG : Thanks for taking time to response.I have added details about the process.

Answer (score 0):

use impala which is Netezza on Hadoop, try Kudu for real time and batch or use HBase for real time and impala for batch , but you can query HBase using impala